# F# Modify & Return

Tags: f#, immutability

```
type Tag(Kids) =
    member this.Kids = Kids

    static member (-) (this: Tag, that: list<obj>) = 
        Tag(that::this.Kids)
```

The point of this code is to construct a new object based on an existing one, but modifying one (or more) fields on the object. Basically, it is a proxy for a `thing.setX(...)` mutator method, except using immutable data.

It looks incredibly ugly and verbose, and I'm sure there must be a better way of doing it while maintaining the immutability of the data, but I haven't figured out how. Is there some syntactically nice way of doing this?

EDIT: Just for clarity, I also have other classes in the hierarchy:

```
type HTMLTag(s, Classes, Kids, Styles) = 
    inherit Tag(Kids)

    member this.NominalTag = s
    member this.Classes = Classes
    member this.Styles: list<String * String> = Styles

    static member (-) (this: HTMLTag, that: list<obj>) = 
        HTMLTag(this.NominalTag, this.Classes, that::this.Kids, this.Styles)
```

Apart from it being very verbose, the `-` function's "copy with modification" thing is completely non-generic: even though I am doing the same thing each time (copy w/ modification to same variable) I have to rewrite the whole thing all over again, which isn't very nice.

One thing I find very annoying is that this would be very simple with mutation:

```
static member (-) (this: Tag, that: list<obj>) = 
    this.Kids = that :: this.Kids
    this
```

But I'm trying to keep everything immutable as far as possible

Comment: See http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/11/lenses-in-f.html :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Copy and update record expressions*<sup>[MSDN]</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx) are meant to handle this exact case. If you can use a record type instead you can do

```
type Tag = 
  { NominalTag : obj
    Classes : obj
    Kids : list<obj>
    Styles : list<String * String> }
  static member (-) (this: Tag, that: list<obj>) = 
    { this with Kids = this.Kids @ that }
```

The compiled forms of this code and yours are virtually identical.

Incidentally, it's odd that the `(-)` operator is being used to append...but I presume this is a contrived case.

#### UPDATE

Now that you've updated your question I'm confused about what you want to do. If you want to return a new object I don't see how mutation helps you.

A more functional approach (vs inheritance) is to separate your data and behaviors, the data being records and the behaviors functions grouped within a module. If you want behavior to be shared across types, use interfaces. Records can implement interfaces.

Comment: Records don't have inheritence, though, do they? My `Tag` class hierarchy has some amount of regular data/functionality that is shared through inheritance; is there any way to achieve a similar effect using records?

Comment: mutation helps because I can simply do a `clone()` to get a new object, change one field and return it to get the effect I want (copy & update). Currently I swapped over to use Records, which works in this case, but I can imagine will have problems for more complex class hierarchies where there is a significant amount of shared behavior down the class hierarchy; even interfaces don't sole the problem of repeat functionality.

Or maybe I just haven't gotten over putting the object's behavior outsite the object (as you mentioned) =)